# MeteorJS: Load spinner while API results are returned

Tags: meteor

I have an app that is consuming an XML data source.

A user can select a category from a dropdown and an API call is made to pull back an XML data-source for processing. A) How do I update my front-end collection with the data? B) How do I show a spinner while the collection is updated?

JavaScript

```
var getJobsByIndustry = function(onet) {
  if(typeof(onet) === "undefined")
      alert("Must include an Onet code");

  var url = "onet=" + onet;

  Meteor.call('retrieveJobs', url, function(error, results){
    console.log(results)
  });
};

Template.selector.events({
  'click div.select-block ul.dropdown-menu li': function(e) {
    var selectedIndex = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel");
    var val = $('select#industryPicker option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('value');
    var oldVal = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');

    if(val != oldVal) {
      Session.set('currentIndustryOnet', val);
      Session.set('jobsLoaded', false);
      getJobsByIndustry(val);
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="list">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{#if jobsLoaded}}
      <ul class="list-group" id="jobs">
        {{#each jobs}}
          <li>
            <span class="pull-right">{{address}}</span>
            <span id="jobTitle">{{title}}</span>
            <span id="company">{{company}}</span>
            <span id="date"><em>{{dateacquired}}</em></span>
          </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{else}}
      {{> spinner}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <select id="perPage" class="selectpicker select-block" _val="{{selected_opt}}">
            <option value="10">10 Per Page</option>
            <option value="25">25 Per Page</option>
            <option value="50">50 Per Page</option>
            <option value="100">100 Per Page</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10">
          {{{pagination}}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be great if you could move your backend to Mongo, instead of processing the XML asynchronously yourself. However, you can accomplish this in the following steps:

- When you make the API call, set a reactive variable (such as a value in `Session`) to some value to indicate that it is being loaded.
- When the API call returns, process the data and insert it into a collection (clearing out anything that was previously there, if it is being reused).
- Set this variable again to indicate that is loaded.

This use case aligns very well with `Meteor.subscribe`, but you'll have to make your own analogies. To display the spinner, just use the reactive variable in a template:

```
<template name="userList">
    <div class="well well-skinny user-list scroll-vertical">
        {{#if loaded}}
            Users:
            {{#each users}}
            {{> userPill}}
            {{/each}}
        {{else}}
            {{> spinner}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Where `loaded` is defined as

```
Template.userList.loaded = -> Session.equals("userSubReady", true)
```

I pulled this example from my app, which uses spinners in several places (https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/tree/master/client/views) as well as the spin.js package for Meteor: https://github.com/SachaG/meteor-spin. Check out the code I linked for more details, if you're interested.